# Is there a way to prove stuff in Idris without a model?

Tags: idris

I have been trying to implement the Incidence Axioms in geometry for Hilbert plane. And came up with the following axioms:

```
interface (Eq point) => Plane line point where
  -- Abstract notion for saying three points lie on the same line.
  colinear : point -> point -> point -> Bool
  coplanar : point -> point -> point -> Bool
  contains : line -> point -> Bool

  -- Intersection between two lines
  intersects_at : line -> line -> point -> Bool
  intersection_def : (contains l a = True) -> (contains m a = True) -> (intersects_at l m a = True)

  -- For any two distinct points there is a line that contains them.
  line_contains_two_points : (a,b : point) -> (a /= b) = True -> (l : line ** (contains l a = True, contains l b = True ))

  -- If two points are contained by l and m then l = m
  two_pts_define_line : contains l a = True -> contains l b = True -> contains m a = True -> contains m b = True -> l = m

  -- There exists 3 non-colinear points.
  three_non_colinear_pts : (a : point ** b : point ** c : point ** (colinear a b c = False, (a /= b) = True, (b /= c) = True, (a /= c) = True))

  -- Any lines contains at least two points.
  contain_two_pts : (l : line) -> (a : point ** b : point ** (contains l a = True, contains l b = True))
```

I want to show that a line intersects with another line at most once. So I came up with the following statement:

```
intersect_at_most_one_point : (l, m : line) -> (a : point) -> (intersects_at l m a = True) -> (intersects_at l m b = True) -> a = b
```

Which reads:

> Given two lines, if they intersect at two points `a` and `b` then it must be that `a = b`.

However I get the error:

```
When checking type of Main.intersect_at_most_one_point:
When checking argument x to type constructor =:
        Can't find implementation for Plane line point
```

So what I suspect this means is that it wants some sort of `data` value that I can show satisfies the idea of an incidence geometry. I interpret this mathematically as I need a model for the system. The problem is there are a lot of of "geometries" which satisfy these axioms that are vastly different.

Is it possible to derive theorems about an interface without the need for any any explicit `data` to work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `Plane` constraint to your type signature of `intersect_at_most_one_point`:

```
intersect_at_most_one_point : Plane line point => 
  (l, m : line) -> (a : point) -> 
  (intersects_at l m a = True) -> (intersects_at l m b = True) -> 
  a = b
```